# MAUI. Save image to byte array

Tags: c#, image, maui

I've an Image (can be downloaded from a WS or added by user via camera ot gallery) shown to user. I need to save in byte array to send to a REST WS. I have not found a way to retrieve from Image or Imagesource the data...

docs google with no solution

Comment: if you are retrieving images from a service, they are probably already a `byte[]`.  Likewise, with the `MediaPicker` you can use `OpenReadAsync` from the `FileResult` object to get the `byte[]`

Comment: You have an ImageSource, and you want to convert it to byte[]? Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the image from web service, you already get a bite array when you download it. And for the image selected by the user on the device, you can use [the file picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=android#pick-a-file) to to that:

```
public async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                using var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // The user canceled or something went wrong
    }

    return null;
}
```